# Combine 2 arrays with different length, repeating the shorter array to match the length of the longer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to ask how to merge 2 *arrays* with different lenght and extending the short one **to match** the long one's length.

```js
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
B = ["a","b","c","d"]

result is array C
C = [
{1,"a"},
{2,"b"},
{3,"c"},
{4,"d"},
{5,"a"},
{6,"b"},
{7,"c"},
{8,"d"},
{9,"a"},
{10,"b"}
]
```

Thanks, sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const 
  A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  B = ["a","b","c","d"];
  
const result = A.map((o,i)=>[o, B[i%B.length]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: wow, that was quick, thanks. could you explain about what happen in `map` ? and how to make the result is an array of objects?

Comment: ok, thank you. i've implemented it with some adjustment in my code, and it works. done.

Comment: @pras Cool. Inside `map`, I am making use `%` operator by dividing the index to array length to get the continuous array index.